# How to fire a Javascript function when a QuickTime movie has finished playing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, quicktime

When a Quicktime movie has ended, I want to replace it with a image slideshow. My current approach is to have the .mov file communicate back to the Javascript on the page. Once the end of the movie is reached, an event calls a function.

So my question is: **What method can I use to call a Javascript function when a Quicktime movie ends?**

I see some ideas here, but it is difficult to put the pieces together. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_JavaScript/bQTScripting_JavaScri_Document/QuickTimeandJavaScri.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001526-CH001-SW5

I am hoping to use the `qt_ended()` function.

Here is my code so far:

```
 <object width="853" height="496" classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab">  
   <param name="enablejavascript" value="true" />
   <param name="postdomevents" value="true" />  
   <param name="src" value="/wp-content/themes/gono9/videos/General_Orders_No9_Trailer1.mov" />  
   <param name="controller" value="true" />  
   <param name="autoplay" value="true" />  
   <param name="scale" value="aspect" />  
   <param name="bgcolor" value="000000" />  
   <param name="cache" value="true" />  
   <embed width="853" height="496" src="/wp-content/themes/gono9/videos/General_Orders_No9_Trailer1.mov" bgcolor="000000" cache="true" type="video/quicktime" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" controller="true" enablejavascript="true" postdomevents="true" autoplay="true" scale="aspect"></embed>  
</object>
```

Does `qt_ended()` go in my .js file?

I need help putting the pieces together.

If looking at the existing website helps: http://generalordersno9.com
This is related to the trailer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered my own question by reading the Apple documentation.

For those interested the code is here:
http://www.generalordersno9.com/wp-content/themes/gono9/js/g.js

And the demo is here:
http://www.generalordersno9.com/

Comment: Thank you prodigitalson for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`qt_ended` isnt necessaily the function name. thats the event name it fires. You have to add the function as a callback to the event. Ive never messed with QT via js but using jquery it would look something like this:

```
var myQuickTime = {
  ended : function() {
    // save a reference to the movie object
    var movie = this;

    // do stuff when the movie has ended
    alert('Movie "#'+$(movie).attr('id')+'" Done!');
  }
};

$(function(){
  // add the listener on dom ready
  $('#mymovie').bind('qt_ended', myQickTime.ended);
});
```

Now im not 100% on using jQuery's `bind` method. It may be for some reason that you have to use baseline js as shown in the examples on the link you posted (see the myAddListener function). I wouldnt think this is the case because this is part of what jQuery's `bind` method does, but you never know :-)

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, Apple's javaScript interface for QuickTime is broken, and has been for years. There is no indication that they will fix it. You're supposed to use HTML5 video (which has a proper, functional 'ended' event that works).

If you are lucky, your QT movie is already using H264 or some other MPEG-4 codec, in which case, it might just work with the HTML5 video tag, although you might need to save as.. or export with a m4v extension first.